# Encountered java.io.FileNotFoundException while parsing a rss feed in java

Tags: java, xml, filenotfoundexception

I couldn't figure out the reason why i get this error while i try to parse an feed using sax parser.The code is simple and it has been an working code for many other url's.

```
    try{
         String myurl="http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=n&output=rss"

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        spf.setValidating(false);
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        xr.setContentHandler(this);

        URL com = new URL(urls);
        URLConnection con = com.openConnection();
        con.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        is = new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        xr.parse(is);
    } catch (Exception e) {... }
```

The error i am getting is

```
  07-30 18:15:28.713: WARN/System.err(596): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=n&output=rss
  07-30 18:15:28.763: WARN/System.err(596): at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1064)
  07-30 18:15:28.763: WARN/System.err(596): at com.mycityway.commonparsers.CommonParser.createFeed(CommonParser.java:311)    
  ...
```

please suggest me the correct way of doing this

Comment: I guess you have done that a few times too often, and google sends your site scraper an error 404, as they determined that you violate their terms of usage.

Comment: You could try posting the actual code that's getting the error, since what you posted won't compile. `myurl` isn't used, and `urls` isn't defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do plain and simple browser checking via the *User-Agent* header. If they don't like it, they send a 403 (forbidden). Simply add one generic and it works. The following line is the first thing I try whenever I encounter this problem and it works close to always:

```
URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
urlc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "firefox");
```